# Flask function takes one argument, 2 given

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to pass the data from my WTForm, using `form.consumer_key.data`, but I get an argument saying I'm passing in two arguments. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my error

```
File "/Users/Gaby/Documents/Code/Twitty/app/views.py", line 18, in authenticate
```

Here's my route where I'm trying to pass the file

```
auth = TwitterAuth()

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/authenticate', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def authenticate():
    form = TwitterAuthForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        #this is where my error is happening
        auth.set_consumer_key(form.consumer_key.data)
        auth.set_consumer_secret(form.consumer_secret.data)
        auth.set_access_token(form.access_token.data)
        auth.set_access_secret(form.access_secret.data)
        return redirect('/index.html')

return render_template('authenticate.html',
        title='Sign In',
        form=form)
```

My TwitterAuth() implementation is just getters and setters

```
class TwitterAuth(): 
        consumer_key = "" 
        consumer_secret = "" 
        access_token = "" 
        access_secret = "" 

        def set_consumer_key(ck): 
                consumer_key = ck 

        def set_consumer_secret(cs): 
                consumer_secret = cs 

        def set_access_token(at): 
                access_token = at 

        def set_access_secret(access_sec):
                access_secret = access_sec

        def get_consumer_key():
                return consumer_key

        def get_consumer_secret():
                return consumer_secret

        def get_access_token():
                return access_token

        def get_access_secret():
                return access_secret
```

Comment: Your error message is clipped. Please paste the whole error message.

Comment: What happens when you try `auth.consumer_key = form.consumer_key.data`?  You don't need setter methods in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the methods in the TwitterAuth class have a `self` parameter, that's why you get the error.

In Python, every instance method must have `self` as it's first parameter.

(Actually it can be called anything, but `self` is the conventional name: you won't see any other name used).

EDIT:

Furthermore, in your getter and setter methods you should return `self.attribute_name` and assign to `self.attribute_name` so that you are returning and setting the values of attributes of the `TwitterAuth` instance, otherwise you will encounter more errors.

Comment: They could also all be changed to class methods because there doesn't seem to be a need for instance variables

Comment: @cricket_007 Actually no, because the OP probably intends to set instance variables in the method bodies, but is neglecting to assign to `self.attr_name` - oherwise the assignments are meaningless.

Comment: Yeah, I was reading up on class variables and you still need self. I think the pythonic approach would just not use getters and setters because they are largely unnecessary

Comment: @cricket_007 I've updated the answer to mention fixing the method bodies.  On the whole I agree with you - TwitterAuth could just be a `dict` - but the question is about the exception rather than design.